# After mapping an array , how do I return a logo component inside a Vertical-Timeline ? react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a timeline element (using react-vertical-timeline-component) that will contain a different amount of logos in each element.
The problem I'm facing is that I've already mapped the elements and the element.icons but I don't really know how do I return the Icon element without returning it directly (I've bold up the example)

---

Skills.js

```
import React from 'react'
import './Skills.css'
import { VerticalTimeline, VerticalTimelineElement }  from 'react-vertical-timeline-component';
import timelineElements from "./Data";
import "react-vertical-timeline-component/style.min.css";
import { ReactComponent as SchoolIcon } from "./Assets/school.svg";
import { ReactComponent as ReduxLogo } from './Assets/redux.svg'

function Skills({ id }) {
    const schoolIconStyles = { background: "#ffffff" };
    return (
      <>
        <div className="head" id={id}>
          <VerticalTimeline>
            <title className="title">Education</title>
            {timelineElements.map((element) => {
              let listItems = element.icons.map(({icon}) => {
                return **<ReduxLogo className="element-icon"/>**
              })
              return (
                <VerticalTimelineElement
                  key={element.key}
                  iconStyle={schoolIconStyles}
                  icon={<SchoolIcon/>}
                >
                  <h3 className="element-title">{element.title}</h3>
                  {listItems}
                </VerticalTimelineElement>
              );
            })}
          </VerticalTimeline>
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
  
  export default Skills;
```

---

Data.js

```
import { ReactComponent as CLogo } from './Assets/c.svg'
import { ReactComponent as CssLogo } from './Assets/css.svg'
import { ReactComponent as DartLogo } from './Assets/dart.svg'
import { ReactComponent as FlutterLogo } from './Assets/flutter.svg'
import { ReactComponent as HtmlLogo } from './Assets/html.svg'
import { ReactComponent as JavaLogo } from './Assets/java.svg'
import { ReactComponent as JsLogo } from './Assets/javascript.svg'
import { ReactComponent as PhpLogo } from './Assets/php.svg'
import { ReactComponent as PythonLogo } from './Assets/python.svg'
import { ReactComponent as ReactLogo } from './Assets/react.svg'
import { ReactComponent as SqlLogo } from './Assets/sql.svg'
import { ReactComponent as GitLogo } from './Assets/git.svg'
import { ReactComponent as ReduxLogo } from './Assets/redux.svg'


const timelineElements = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "First Year",
    icons: [<CLogo/>,<JavaLogo/>]

  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Second Year",
    icons: [HtmlLogo,CssLogo,JsLogo,PhpLogo,SqlLogo]
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Third Year",
    icons: [PythonLogo,FlutterLogo,DartLogo]
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: "Today",
    icons: [ReactLogo,GitLogo,ReduxLogo]
  },
];

export default timelineElements;
```

---

Skills.css

```
.head {
  background: #161415;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: rgb(53, 53, 53);
  position: relative;
  height: 1000px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover !important;
 -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.title {
  font-size: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
}

.element-icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin:12px 12px 12px 12px;
}

.element-title {

}

.element-list {
}

.vertical-timeline-element-title{
  font-size: 36px;
}

.h3 {
  padding-top: 0.25em;
}

.vertical-timeline-element-content {
  box-shadow: 0 0.25em 0.5em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25),
    0 0.4em 1.25em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) !important;
  padding: 2em 3em !important;
}

.schoolButton {
  background-color: #f9c74f;
}

.schoolButton:hover {
  background-color: #f3bc3c;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1700px) {
  .vertical-timeline-element-date {
    display: block !important;
    float: none !important;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 1.5em;
  }
}
```

Comment: What you wanted to do in map? 

let listItems = element.icons.map(({icon}) => {
                return **<ReduxLogo className="element-icon"/>**
              })

Comment: I wanted to display a list of logos inside a vertical-timeline-element

Answer (score 2):

For the part where bolding is intended - you have to check if the `icon` is a `react-element` eg. `<CLogo/>` or a `react-component` eg. `HtmlLogo`. In case it is an element - it is jsx parsable without any change - so you may return `icon` and otherwise render the component - `<icon/>`; But returning `<icon/>` wont go through - because it would be taken as a html-native element rather than the variable. So rename `icon` as `Icon` and return aptly, i.e. `<Icon/>`. This conditional is due to the fact that the `Data.js` file has mixed `icons`.

In case you want to change the `react-element`, you would return it as `<icon.type {...icon.props} />`; It is handy if you want to pass any additional props to the element.

Comment: By mistake I've added the mixed icons so its suppose to be taken as a String, mb.
I think im aware about the diffrences between element and component but maybe not quite well to understand as if there's a problem only where I bolded ?

Comment: @DeanShaked - please elaborate more on the issue. AFA the bold statement goes, there is nothing wrong there. An SVG file can be imported as you have done with the `ReduxLogo` in a typical CRA based setup; But in that line the `icon` isn't used in any manner - so again, what is it that you want to say through the question - could you be more specific and may be add error(s), if you are having some. Also, if the `icon` is gonna be a `string` then you would need a proper component to render it.